# ncat only achieving 36kB/s

Tags: windows, netcat

I'm experimenting with nmap's ncat on windows. I'm using on Host A:

```
ncat.exe -v -l 9991 < my_big_test_file
```

and on Host B:

```
ncat.exe -v [HOST-A-IP] 9991 > test_dump
```

where on Host A there is a port forwarding configured for port 9991 to the actual host.

Monitoring the network activity with the resource monitor, I noticed that there is a short burst when Host B openes the connection but quickly the transfer rate drops to 36 kB/s. I disabled the router's firewall features completely, however have the Windows Firewall on Host A enabled (with an allow rule established)

What could cause this slow transfer rate?